# How can I remove the blank space in the Activity that is shown as a Dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-titlebar

[image]
**Hello, This is a Dialog Activity. I want to remove the blank space. How can I make it? Unfortunately, I am stuck.Thanks in advance..**

### This is my styles file

```
 <style name="ThemeDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

## This is my Manifest.xml

```
  <activity
                android:name=".Activities.AboutActivity"
                android:label="@string/hakkinda"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeDialog"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

### This my onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

### This is my activity_about

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activities.AboutActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your ThemeDialog style to this:

```
<style name="ThemeDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

And maybe in your activity root layout your should add a paddingTop and paddingBottom instead of hard coding the height.

Answer (score 2):

A fragment will reserve that space for the title bar. To remove it you need to over-ride `onCreateDialog`:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    // request a window without the title
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it didnt work for me. I am using API 16 and there is not any method like that you used.

Answer (score 1):

In your "activity_about" file, change the value for `'android:paddingTop'`until you get the desired effect (I changed it to 0dp):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply remove paddingTop from your mainactivity xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: Please don't add only code as an answer, but include an explanation and describe how your answer solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: yeah tried to add an explanation several times but not done. don't know the issue. here is the explanation : simply remove paddingTop from your mainactivity xml