# Alert Dialog has white space over title

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add a simple dialog with a title but for some reason it has a white margin on top.

The code that i use is:

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
            builder.setTitle("Test")
                    .setMessage("This is a weird dialog")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create().show();
```

and it looks like this on my Nexus 5X with Android 7.1.1:

[image]

Is there supposed to be such a big margin on top?

As the parent for my app theme I use:

```
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Post relevant theme code please.

Comment: I updated my post with the parent of my app theme. Besides that I have made no theme specific changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got rid of it by not using the `Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert` theme. Instead I made a custom design with `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"` as a parent.

Answer (score 9):

Instead

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
```

use

```
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar);
```

Comment: Perfect for when you were more than happy with the default dialog theme, just not the excessive gap left for unused features.

Comment: Tried so many combinations but this one worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem. I solved it by changing my Import from `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` to `android.app.AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Dialog Theme, please see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510940/6421759

**Cheers!**

Comment: Thanks, the suggested answer removed the space on top but made the whole dialog small and cut off the message. I just solved it by not using Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert theme and instead wrote a custom design.

Comment: If the answer removed the space, please accept my answer because resolve the issue (the blank space)